# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type: not '[AVCaptureDevice]'

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Following the repo and tutorial: https://github.com/brianadvent/CustomCamera

I am getting error with the following code:
Error:

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'
```

```
      if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices {
            captureDevice = availableDevices.first
            beginSession()
        }
```

Similarly, with the following segment

```
if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
            self.previewLayer = previewLayer
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
            captureSession.startRunning()

            let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

            dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
            }

            captureSession.commitConfiguration()


            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.brianadvent.captureQueue")
            dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)



        }
```

Error associated with second code snippet:
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'

Comment: You're trying to unwrap something that isn't an optional. Just don't unwrap it, and directly assign it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change.

```
if let availableDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices.first {
        captureDevice = availableDevice
        beginSession()
    }
```

Hope you get the point.

devices(an array) was not an optional, that is, you will surely get the array. But, `devices.first`is an optional, because the array might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to unwrap something that isn't an optional. Just don't unwrap it, and directly assign it to a variable, as you did with `dataOutput`.